# Filter groups of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the dataset I've got.
Person, Format and different roles (bit).
I would like to get all the rows where each *Format* group has all 3 roles selected. For ex: Novel format does not have Editor role selected. So I would like to get data that does not contain *Novel* records.
How can I achieve that?

[image]

Comment: do You want select all registers where WRITER, DIRECTOR, EDITOR is set to 1?

Comment: You already got 3 answers,Still, I request you to elaborate your question a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question is "I would like to get all the rows where each Format group has all 3 roles selected."  You can approach this with window functions:

```
select name, format, write, director, editor
from (select t.*,
             max(cast(writer as int)) over (partition by format) as maxwriter,
             max(cast(director as int)) over (partition by format) as maxdirector,
             max(cast(editor as int)) over (partition by format) as maxeditor
      from table t
     ) t
where maxwriter = 1 and maxdirector = 1 and maxeditor = 1;
```

If you want to get rows where there is no editor, you can use a similar approach, just change the `where` clause:

```
where maxwriter = 1 and maxdirector = 1 and maxeditor = 0;
```

Comment: It looks like this would suffice - `select * from tablez where w = 1 and d = 1 and e = 1 and format != 'novel'`. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev . . . Yes.  You are missing the fact that the `1`s are on different rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
select format
from your_table
group by format
having sum(case when writer = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
and sum(case when director = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
and sum(case when editor = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

and if you need the complete row instead of only `format` then you can do

```
select * from your_table
where format in 
(
    select format
    from your_table
    group by format
    having sum(case when writer = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
    and sum(case when director = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
    and sum(case when editor = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the query:

```
select * from (
    select format, count(*) as total_count    
    from table    
    group by format    
) as t1    
inner join (    
    select format, count(*) as total_count
    from table
    where writer=1 and director=1 and editor=1
    group by format
) as t2
on t1.format=t2.format and t1.total_count=t2.total_count
```

the main idea - calculate how many rows has each format and then calculate how many rows satisfy your conditions

Comment: It looks like this would suffice - `select * from tablez where w = 1 and d = 1 and e = 1 and format != 'novel'`. Am I missing something ?